Determining the Rectangular Region where the Function Satisfies the Lipschitz Condition
This is my first time asking a question on Stack Exchange, and I'm currently facing a problem related to an ordinary differential equation. I am trying to determine the rectangular region where the function $$f(x,y)=|ln y|+x^2$$ satisfies the Lipschitz condition.
In other words, I need to find the range where the following inequality holds:
$$\left|\frac{|ln y_1| - |ln y_2| + x_1^2 - x_2^2}{y_1 - y_2}\right| \leq L$$
I have tried several methods but haven't been able to figure it out. Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

For the Lipschitz condition you have $x_1=x_2$. What remains is a difference quotient. Apply the mean-value theorem.
